# Rails :dependent => destroy with conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Say I have dogs, leashes, and owners... If I destroy a leash I want to destroy the dog too.. but not if the dog has an owner..

Comment: You can use a callback after_destroy for that. See [this answer][1] for details.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6049806/rails-aciverecord-use-dependent-destroy-on-condition

Comment: Can you call 'self' after_destroy?

Comment: I didn't try it myself, but I think you can. The model object should still exist even after destroy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't want to use `:dependent => :destroy` here, but rather the `before_destroy` callback like so:

```
#leash.rb

before_destroy :destroy_dog

def destroy_dog
  dog.destroy unless dog.owner
end
```

Comment: I was thinking something like self.dog.destroy unless self.dog.owner

Comment: ...but not sure if you can call self after_destroy

Comment: yep, before_destroy maybe more appropriate here. updated answer accordingly.

Comment: Hey I think you need to put self.dog.destory unless self.dog.owner no?

Comment: `self` is unnecessary here, it is implied.  the reason it works is because ruby tries to find a local variable (ie `dog`) and if it doesn't find it, it sends it to `self`.  try it and see :)

Answer (score 0):

```
class Book < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :author, -> { where active: true },
                        dependent: :destroy
end
```

works for `has_many` too, in which it destroys the objects according to the `where` condition