# Rails 2 dependent => destroy should work after condtion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-1.8.7

Is there any way to destroy dependencies only after checking condition?
This is my Model subject_type.rb

```
class SubjectType < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :subjects, :dependent=>:destroy
  validates_presence_of :name
end
```

If subject_type_id is present in subject table , dependency should not work,

Comment: write a method with a callback of `before_destroy` and in this method you can check condition whatever you want. This callback will be in subject.rb

Comment: have you include `belongs_to :subject_type` in Subject model?

Comment: Yeah I have included.,

Comment: see this. this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6049806/rails-aciverecord-use-dependent-destroy-on-condition